# redirect to page after itemadding in list withlong run operation

Tags: event-receivers, redirect, splongoperation

after many checking about redirecting to page from event recievers I understood that my best option it to di it from itemadding event and not itemadded.

that does not means that I can neglect the itemadded event code that I had, so in item adding event I called  a page which in it there is a SPLongRunningOperation, and there  actually the itemadded event code it running.

after the code it finished I calls :

```
         operation.EndScript(window.frameElement.commitPopup());
```

to close the dialog (dialog that opened while adding new item to a list)

My problem is that after closing that dialog I want to redirect to another page , and no stay on my list... 
I tired many things nothing works for me....

Hope for guideness 
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that code in your event receiver:

```
class CustomEventHandler : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    private HttpContext currentContext;

    public CustomEventHandler() : base()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
        }
    }

    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPUtility.Redirect("{url}", SPRedirectFlags.Default, currentContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: I came across that solution, this is tempting enough to try but as I read ItemAdded is a synchronous event and there is a purpose why the context is null in it, and even if you get the context to be full it might not always work...
but as a last resort I will use this.
TIA